# RESTKit 0.2x top level mapping of arrays

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

Have some questions on RESTKit 0.2x. Relatively new to RESTKit, so forgive my ignorance on some topics.

Let's say I have this JSON (This example is from Google Geocoding and the url is `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true`):

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "1600",
                    "short_name": "1600",
                    "types": [
                        "street_number"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Amphitheatre Parkway",
                    "short_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
                    "types": [
                        "route"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Mountain View",
                    "short_name": "Mountain View",
                    "types": [
                        "locality",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Santa Clara County",
                    "short_name": "Santa Clara County",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "California",
                    "short_name": "CA",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "United States",
                    "short_name": "US",
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "94043",
                    "short_name": "94043",
                    "types": [
                        "postal_code"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.4219988,
                    "lng": -122.083954
                },
                "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 37.42334778029149,
                        "lng": -122.0826050197085
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 37.42064981970849,
                        "lng": -122.0853029802915
                    }
                }
            },
            "types": [
                "street_address"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

And what I am looking is to map the array of "long_name" into CoreData which have a `NSManagedObject` with a string called "long_name".

**The reason being that my backend API standard will include some metadata along with the information and I want to map after the first level (or in this case, two levels deep) into CoreData. So in short, for answers like "why don't you create a "address_components" object and then map the array to it, will not work for me.**

So with this JSON, I will have three rows in CD storing the different long name. To keep it short, I am limiting the primary ID.
And I end up getting an error like this:

```
"Error Domain=org.restkit.RKValueTransformers.ErrorDomain Code=3002 \"The given value is not already an instance of 'NSString'\" UserInfo=0x9b808c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The given value is not already an instance of 'NSString'}",
```

This is how my mapping data look like:

```
+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {
    // Create a singleton instance of the mapping object.
    __strong static RKEntityMapping *_mapping = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore];
        _mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) inManagedObjectStore:store];
        [_mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"long_name": @"long_name"}];

    });
    return _mapping;
}
```

And the Response Descriptor I got here:

```
[objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[object mapping] // from the mapping function up top
    method:RKRequestMethodGET
    pathPattern:kIRISAPIResourcePath_GoogleElevationAPI
    keyPath:@"results.address_components"
    statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]]];
```

I am pretty much stumped on this. Thoughts? I've look at https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping#mapping-values-without-key-paths and it didn't really answer what I needed.

**=== UPDATED ERROR LOG ====**

```
2013-10-23 15:29:08.226 IRIS[1518:f03] D restkit.object_mapping:RKPropertyInspector.m:131 Cached property inspection for Class 'GoogleMaps': {
    long_name = {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = long_name;
    };
}
2013-10-23 15:29:08.226 IRIS[1518:3a0f] E restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:431 Failed transformation of value at keyPath 'long_name' to representation of type 'NSString': Error Domain=org.restkit.RKValueTransformers.ErrorDomain Code=3002 "Failed transformation of value '(
    1600,
    "Amphitheatre Parkway",
    "Mountain View",
    "Santa Clara County",
    California,
    "United States",
    94043
)' to NSString: none of the 2 value transformers consulted were successful." UserInfo=0x991d270 {detailedErrors=(
    "Error Domain=org.restkit.RKValueTransformers.ErrorDomain Code=3002 \"The given value is not already an instance of 'NSString'\" UserInfo=0x9915ff0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The given value is not already an instance of 'NSString'}",
    "Error Domain=org.restkit.RKValueTransformers.ErrorDomain Code=3000 \"Expected an `inputValue` of type `NSNull`, but got a `__NSArrayI`.\" UserInfo=0x9932900 {NSLocalizedDescription=Expected an `inputValue` of type `NSNull`, but got a `__NSArrayI`.}"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Failed transformation of value '(
    1600,
    "Amphitheatre Parkway",
    "Mountain View",
    "Santa Clara County",
    California,
    "United States",
    94043
)' to NSString: none of the 2 value transformers consulted were successful.}
```

**==== UPDATE ENDS ====**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`results` in your JSON is a problem because it's an array (so you can navigate into it with a keypath. It also isn't in your keypath currently so RestKit doesn't find the correct start point. Other than that your mapping is fine.

To deal with `results` you either need to change the JSON (from the server or once received) or create a mapping for the results (with a relationship to apply the address mapping to the nested data).

Comment: hmm..i tried, with the `results.address_components` as a keyPath and it still doesn't work. Are you talking about doing a mapping relationship?

Comment: I've updated my Error logs. This is AFTER I added results to the keyPath in my `RKResponseDescriptor`

Comment: Setting the keypath to `results.address_components` won't work because it will try to process an array of arrays and that isn't what you're mapping expects. I'm talking about having 2 mappings with a relationship between them.

Comment: I will mark this as an answer because of the relationship created between `address_component` and `results` fixed the mapping failed error. However, @Wain, do you know if I could map straight into the array presented in the `results` section without doing a relationship in RESTKit? Like it is Mapping without KVC by bypassing `results` and then consider it's value as first level array. Hope I made sense on what I said there.

Comment: Without the relationship you would have only KVC. So you'd basically just have a standard JSON parse with no mapping.